# Instantiating appropriate WebApplicationException subclass

Tags: java, jax-rs, http-response-codes

JAX-RS has a general `WebApplicationException` class for encapsulating any HTTP response status code and reason phrase. But there are many code-specific subclasses. For example `NotFoundException` indicates an HTTP 404 not found response code, although one could have created a general `WebApplicationException` instance with a response code of 404.

Is there some simple way for me to take a non-success HTTP response code and create the appropriate `WebApplicationException` subclass (one of those defined in the JAX-RS API)? Or am I forced to create a factory method with a big `switch` statement to do this?